# how do i get the value for the acceleration?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Im creating a programme to calculate average acceleration.It works just fine but i can't seem to get the value for acceleration.Can anyone teach me why this happens and how to solve this?
tq for helping

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void Getdata(double &Vstart, double &Vend, double &time);
void calculate(double &Vstart, double &Vend, double &time, double &accel);
void Displayoutput(double &out);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int main() {
  double Vstart = 0.0;
  double Vend = 0.0;
  double time = 0.0;
  double accel,out = 0;

  cout << "please enter your velocity(Vo=m/s)\n,velocity(Vt=m/s)\nand time(s=second)\n\n";
  Getdata(Vstart, Vend, time);
  calculate(Vstart, Vend, time, accel);
  Displayoutput(out);
  return 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void Getdata(double &Vstart, double &Vend, double &time) {
  cin >> Vstart;
  cin >> Vend;
  cin >> time;
  cout << "your Vo=" << Vstart << " ,Vt=" << Vend << " and T=" << time << "\n\n";
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void calculate(double &Vstart, double &Vend, double &time, double &accel) {
  accel = (Vstart - Vend) / time;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void Displayoutput(double &out) {

  cout << "the acceleration =" << out;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Comment: You print the value of `out`, which was assigned `0` and never changed since. You don't print the computed value of `accel`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Displayoutput(out);
```

to

```
Displayoutput(accel);
```